# Customer session is not working when i login for first time due to cacheable= true

Tags: magento2.3, customer-session, customer-login, sessions

I have created a ViewModel with below code:

```
<?php
 namespace {ClassNameSpace};
 class {ClassName} implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
 {
    private $context;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context)
    {
       $this->context = $context;
    }   
    public function isLogin()
    {
      return $this->context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }
 }
```

$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();

$loginStatus = $viewModel->isLogin();

```
                   <?php if($loginStatus){ // login menu ?> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/");?>">My Account <i class="fas fa-user ml-2"></i></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/logout");?>">Logout <i class="fas fa-power-off ml-2"></i></a>
                <?php }else{ // non login user ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('online-dealers'); ?>">Online Dealers <i class="fas fa-globe ml-2"></i></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('dealer-locator'); ?>">Dealer locator <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt ml-2"></i></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/login");?>">Dealer Login <i class="fas fa-user ml-2"></i></a> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/create');?>">Become A Dealer <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up ml-2"></i></a>
                    <?php } ?>
```

when I log-in as a dealer first it redirects to the customer page and shows the login menu because the customer page block cacheable=false but when I visit the homepage first it shows a non-login menu but when I refresh then it will show the corrected login menu.

Why is the first time not showing the login menu when block cacheable=true?

Comment: do you want to check current customer login status?

Comment: there is a different menu links for login as well as guest user